# UINavigationController with a background image that remains still and does not animate when the view controllers are pushed or popped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to use **UINavigationController** with a background image that remains still and does not animate when the view controllers are pushed or popped?

Same effect can be achieved by having a paged **UIScrollView** and a **UIImageView** underneath it but I would like to use **UINavigationController** so methods like `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidDisappear` are called, and I can use **UINavigationController's** logic for popping and pushing view controllers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is quite easy. Add an image to the window (or whatever is at the back of your view heirachy), then make the uiviewcontroller main views have transaparent backgrounds. This works on iOS 4 and above.